# How to get Number of methods required to reset for all users via Graph Api

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get "users->password reset->Authentication methods ->  " via Graph Api ( see attach )
Can't  find it for users , please advice
[image]

Comment: The AzureAD portal makes a call to https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/PasswordReset/PasswordResetPolicies for this info: this is an internal API. I couldn't find an alternative in MS Graph (not in V1 or the beta) so I guess you're out of luck (or you'll have to use the undocumented and unsupported main.aim.ad.ext.azure.com api.. Getting a token for this service usually isn't very hard, you can reverse engineer the clientids etc by using a web debugger like Fiddler)

Answer (score 0):

You can check by yourself the documentation about [Identity and access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) but I couldn't find any method or property that gets number of methods required to reset.

Resources:

[Authentication methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong , you are looking for graph API to check authentication methods , by using POST - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/authentication/methods](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser_id%7D/authentication/methods) you can check the list of your authentication methods

For more please check the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-methods?view=graph-rest-1.0

And if you want to reset the password ,

if you are using passwordMethods , you have to use

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6ea91a8d-e32e-41a1-b7bd-d2d185eed0e0/authentication/passwordMethods/28c10230-6103-485e-b985-444c60001490/resetPassword
Content-type: application/json

{
"newPassword": "Cuyo5459"
}

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope this helps

Comment: you are talking about one user but my case is different. i will not reset the password for one user i would like to change the password reset policy